# Publishing a pointcloud problem

Tags: ros, kinect, publish, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm trying to publish a pointcloud that contains the narfkeypoints extracted from a range image with the following code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h>

// PCL specific includes
#include <pcl/ros/conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>

#include <pcl/features/narf.h>
#include <pcl/keypoints/narf_keypoint.h>
#include <pcl/range_image/range_image.h>
#include <pcl/features/range_image_border_extractor.h>
#include <pcl/range_image/range_image_planar.h>
    
typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointCloud<int> > PointCloud;
typedef pcl::PointXYZ PointType;

ros::Publisher pub;

pcl::PointCloud<int> keypoint_indices;

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr keypoints_ptr (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>& keypoints = *keypoints_ptr;
    

float angular_resolution_;
float support_size_ =0.2f;//-0.1f

void depthimage_cb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr &depth_msg)
{
    const uint16_t* depthImage = reinterpret_cast<const uint16_t*>(&depth_msg->data[0]);

    pcl::RangeImagePlanar range_image_;
    pcl::RangeImageBorderExtractor range_image_border_extractor_;

    // convert the depth-image to a pcl::rangeImage
    angular_resolution_ = (float)(-1);
    range_image_.setDepthImage(depthImage,depth_msg->width, depth_msg->height, (depth_msg->width)/2, (depth_msg->height)/2, 600.0, 600.0, angular_resolution_);
      
    range_image_.setUnseenToMaxRange();
    pcl::NarfKeypoint keypoint_det;

    // extract the indices of the NARF-Keypoints
    keypoint_det.getParameters ().support_size =  support_size_;
    keypoint_det.setRangeImageBorderExtractor (&range_image_border_extractor_);
    keypoint_det.setRangeImage (&range_image_);
    keypoint_det.compute (keypoint_indices);
    
    keypoints.points.resize (keypoint_indices.points.size ());
    for (size_t i=0; i<keypoint_indices.points.size (); ++i)
    keypoints.points[i].getVector3fMap () = range_image_.points[keypoint_indices.points[i]].getVector3fMap ();
   // pub.publish (keypoints);
} 

int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Initialize ROS
  ros::init (argc, argv, "keypointsplanar");
  ros::NodeHandle nh1;
  ros::NodeHandle nh2;

  // Create a ROS subscriber for the input point cloud
  ros::Subscriber sub2 = nh1.subscribe ("/camera/depth/image", 1, depthimage_cb);   

  // Create a ROS publisher for the output point cloud
  //pub = nh2.advertise<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>& keypoints> ("keypoints", 1);

  // Spin
  ros::spin ();
}
```

If I comment the pub.publish (keypoints); and the pub = nh2.advertisepcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ& keypoints> ("keypoints", 1); lines the code compiles with no problems or warnings, however, if I uncomment them I keep getting these errors:

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------[ rosmake ] [ make ] [ tesis: 11.3 sec ]                                                              [ 1 Active 29/30 Complete ]
from /home/jumpei/fuerte_workspace/tesis/src/keypointsplanar.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::MD5Sum::value(const M&) [with M = pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ]’:
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_traits.h:255:104:   instantiated from ‘const char* ros::message_traits::md5sum(const M&) [with M = pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ]’
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/publisher.h:112:7:   instantiated from ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const [with M = pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ]’
/home/jumpei/fuerte_workspace/tesis/src/keypointsplanar.cpp:57:27:   instantiated from here
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_traits.h:126:34: error: ‘const class pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ’ has no member named ‘__getMD5Sum’
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::DataType::value(const M&) [with M = pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ]’:
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_traits.h:264:106:   instantiated from ‘const char* ros::message_traits::datatype(const M&) [with M = pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ]’
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/publisher.h:112:7:   instantiated from ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const [with M = pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ]’
/home/jumpei/fuerte_workspace/tesis/src/keypointsplanar.cpp:57:27:   instantiated from here
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_traits.h:143:36: error: ‘const class pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ’ has no member named ‘__getDataType’
In file included from /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/publisher.h:34:0,
from /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/node_handle.h:32,
from /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/ros.h:45,
from /home/jumpei/fuerte_workspace/tesis/src/keypointsplanar.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h: In static member function ‘static uint32_t ros::serialization::Serializer::serializedLength(typename boost::call_traits::param_type) [with T = pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ, uint32_t = unsigned int, typename boost::call_traits::param_type = const pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ&]’:
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:170:43:   instantiated from ‘uint32_t ros::serialization::serializationLength(const T&) [with T = pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ, uint32_t = unsigned int]’
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:805:45:   instantiated from ‘ros::SerializedMessage ros::serialization::serializeMessage(const M&) [with M = pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ]’
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/publisher.h:118:7:   instantiated from ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const [with M = pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ]’
/home/jumpei/fuerte_workspace/tesis/src/keypointsplanar.cpp:57:27:   instantiated from here
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:142:34: error: ‘const class pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ’ has no member named ‘serializationLength’
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h: In static member function ‘static void ros::serialization::Serializer::write(Stream&, typename boost::call_traits::param_type) [with Stream = ros::serialization::OStream, T = pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ, typename boost::call_traits::param_type = const pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ&]’:
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:152:3:   instantiated from ‘void ros::serialization::serialize(Stream&, const T&) [with T = pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ, Stream = ros::serialization::OStream]’
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:812:3:   instantiated from ‘ros::SerializedMessage ros::serialization::serializeMessage(const M&) [with M = pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ]’
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/publisher.h:118:7:   instantiated from ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const [with M = pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ]’
/home/jumpei/fuerte_workspace/tesis/src/keypointsplanar.cpp:57:27:   instantiated from here
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:125:5: error: ‘const class pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ’ has no member named ‘serialize’
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::MD5Sum::value(const M&) [with M = pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ]’:
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_traits.h:127:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::DataType::value(const M&) [with M = pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ]’:
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_traits.h:144:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h: In static member function ‘static uint32_t ros::serialization::Serializer::serializedLength(typename boost::call_traits::param_type) [with T = pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ, uint32_t = unsigned int, typename boost::call_traits::param_type = const pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ&]’:
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:143:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/keypointsplanar.dir/src/keypointsplanar.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/jumpei/fuerte_workspace/tesis/build' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/keypointsplanar.dir/all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/jumpei/fuerte_workspace/tesis/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jumpei/fuerte_workspace/tesis/build'

I have no idea what to make out of these errors

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41755/publishing-a-pointcloud-problem/) by [David Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2917/david-bravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-08-18**:
What versions of ROS and PCL are you using, and what OS are you on?

**Comment by [David Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2917/david-bravo/) on 2012-08-20**:
Thank you Allenh, I wasn't including pcl_ros/point_cloud.h. Now I feel stupid. I'm using ROS Fuerte and the ros-fuerte-perception-pcl-fuerte-unstable package because I need the NARF keypoints. Now the topic is published but I can't see it in RVIZ because I get a "No message received" error.

**Comment by [David Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2917/david-bravo/) on 2012-08-20**:
I made another question here: http://answers.ros.org/question/41862/no-message-received-in-rviz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at this question: http://answers.ros.org/question/35368/pointcloud-library-publishing/

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0